# Add a View on bottom end of another View... Like layout_below of Android

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, cocoa-touch

I am a developer for Android who is starting with the development for iOS.
I think I have some vices from the development environment for Android.

With Android when I want to add a View below another, use the layout_below property in LayoutParams.

I need to do this via code. I have a UIImageView and UILabel. I want to put UILabel below the UIImageView

Important: The UIImageView has indeterminate height.

I need to do this programmatically.

Please, see this image:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create an `NSLayoutConstraint` to position the label below the image view. Something like:

```
[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:myLabel attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:myImageView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom multiplier:1.0f constant:0.0f];
```

Alternatively, you can calculate where the top of the label should be using `CGRectGetMaxY(myImageView.frame)` and set the y-coordinate of your `UILabel`'s `frame` to that value.

Answer (score 0):

In iOS you will need to use `addSubView:`to add your label to the parent view. You position the label below the image by either setting the `frame` of the label or by using `constraints` if you are using auto layout.